# LWJGL int vertex attribute not working in shader

Tags: opengl, java, glsl, lwjgl

I'm trying to send an integer attribute to my GLSL shader. The shader receives the attribute as follows:

```
layout (location = 3) in int integer_value;
```

I'm creating the attribute as follows:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.integerValueVboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, integer_values_buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, GL_INT, false, 0, 0);
```

`this.integerValueVboId` is a valid ID generated with all the other VBOs. `integer_values_buffer` is an `IntBuffer` confirmed to contain the correct integer values.

When I set one of the integer values to `1`, the shader receives the integer value `1065353216`, which I have found to be the value obtained when one interprets a float `1.0f` as an integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying an integer attribute you need to use [glVertexAttribIPointer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml):

> For glVertexAttribPointer, if normalized is set to GL_TRUE, it indicates that values stored in an integer format are to be mapped to the range [-1,1] (for signed values) or [0,1] (for unsigned values) when they are accessed and converted to floating point. Otherwise, values will be converted to floats directly without normalization.
>
> For glVertexAttribIPointer, only the integer types GL_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_SHORT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_INT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT are accepted. **Values are always left as integer values**.

(My emphasis)